# WPF hide a window in Closing event prevents from application terminating

Tags: c#, wpf, window, hide

A simple question again.

I am using a window in a WPF as a child window, where I would rather have the 'X' button hide the window instead of close. For that, I have:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
   this.Hide();
   e.Cancel = true;
}
```

The problem is that when the parent window is closed, this never closes and keeps the app alive.

Is there a clean way to deal with this? I thought of adding a Kill flag to all my user controls (windows):

```
public bool KillMe;

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
   KillMe = false;
}

private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
   this.Hide();
   if (!KillMe) e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Then in MainWindow_Closing() I would have to set all window KillMe flags to true.

Any better way than creating additional flags and forgetting to set them before closing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could call [Shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdown.aspx) in the "parent's" closing handler...  This will cause your Cancel to be ignored.

From [Window.Closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing.aspx):

> If Shutdown is called, the Closing event for each window is raised. However, if Closing is canceled, cancellation is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

I usualy have my own `AppGeneral` static class for such cases. When I'm realy exiting app I'm setting `AppGeneral.IsClosing` static bool to true. And then, when closing:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
if (!AppGeneral.IsClosing)   
   { 
     this.Hide();
     e.Cancel = true;
   }
}
```

Also, you can kill the your own process (that's ugly but working :) ) `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();`

Answer (score 2):

You should use

`Application.Current.Shutdown();`

inside your master window closing method.

This should override canceling of any subwindow!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and setting ONLY (no extra C# code) ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose" (Application element) in App.xaml did the trick.

Comment: A ShutdownMode of OnMainWindowClose causes WPF to implicitly call Shutdown when the MainWindow closes, even if other windows are currently open. ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.shutdownmode?view=windowsdesktop-8.0